# How to create a custom package to add and manage product

Tags: concrete5

I have tried out packages from concrete 5 
http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/system/packages/

but failed to do so . Could you help me out

Comment: You will need to provide more information than this to get a helpful response.

Comment: A LOT more information.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good starting point:
http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/build-a-single-page-powered-editing-interface-for-concrete5/

If you come from an MVC background and are more familiar with how Ruby On Rails / Kohana / CodeIgniter / etc. work, then I think you might find this boilerplate code I wrote useful as well:
https://github.com/jordanlev/c5_boilerplate_crud